# JPEG decoding using gstreamer on RPI 4

Tags: pi-4, hardware, v4l2, gstreamer, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! fbdevsink sync=False
```

works as expected, it simply uses a USB capture card (https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B087C3NG9W) to stream data from the source to the monitor. Only problem with this pipeline is that the captured footage is choppy. I believe this happens because this pipeline doesn't use the hardware accelrators on the RPI for jpeg decoding and instead use the CPU. So I believe this pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! v4l2jpegdec ! videoconvert ! fbdevsink sync=False
```

The problem is:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Device '/dev/video0' does not support 2:0:0:0 colorimetry
Additional debug info:
../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2object.c(4038): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
Device wants 2:4:5:1 colorimetry
Execution ended after 0:00:00.012490082
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Freeing pipeline ...
```

so I tried

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! omxmjpegdec ! videoconvert ! fbdevsink sync=False
```

which resulted on not having gst-omx installed on the RPI. Tried installing it but it looks like its no longer supported.

Note I am using a RPI 4, 4GB and:

```
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

My questions are:

- Any suggestions on how to speed up such pipeline ?
- If the RPI 4 isn't the hardware to use, any suggestions for better alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding jpegparse in the pipeline before v4l2jpegdec.
If you want to encode with v4l2h264enc afterwards, videoconvert (or v4l2convert) is not required in between.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).